# Is there a way to "delete" a pure virtual function?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have an abstract class with a couple pure virtual functions, and one of the classes I derive from it does not use one of the pure virtual functions:

```
class derivative: public base
{
public:
    int somevariable;
    void somefunction();
};
```

anyways, when I try to compile it, I get an error (apparently, a class is still considered abstract if derive from an abstract class and don't override all pure virtual functions).  Anyways, it seems pointless to define a function

```
int purevirtfunc(){return 0;}
```

just because it needs to be defined through a technicality.  Is there anyway to derive a class from an abstract class and not use one of the abstract class's pure virtual functions?

Comment: If there was a way, what would you expect to happen if code called one of those unimplemented methods?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If your derived class doesn't "use" the base class pure virtual function, then either the derived class should not be derived from the base, or the PVF should not be there. In either case, your design is at fault and needs to be re-thought.

And no, there is no way of deleting a PVF.

Answer (score 14):

A pure virtual class is an interface, one which your code will expect to be fulfilled.  What would happen if you implemented that interface and didn't implement one of the methods?  How would the code calling your interface know that you didn't implement the method?

Your options are:

1. Implement the method as you describe (making it private would indicate that it shouldn't be used).
2. Change your class hierarchy to take into consideration the design change.

Answer (score 9):

The purpose of deriving from abstract classes is that external code can use the abstract class and expect that all functions have been implemented properly. Being able to unimplement a method would defeat this purpose, making the code uncompilable. You're free to throw an exception, if you so choose, however.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a technicality at all.  If your derived class does not exhibit all of the behavior of the parent, it should not be derived from the parent.  This is a major design smell, and you probably need some design refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

When you inherit from a class that has pure virtual functions, you MUST implement those functions.  If you don't, then your derived class is also abstract, and you can't create an object of the derived class.

Comment: You can also create a null implementation that you inherit from that does the stubbing out if you inherit from this interface frequently.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Either provide a default implementation in the base class or a simple implementation in the derived class, as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

There were already good answers, but if you want more info from the theoretical OO design side, check out the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Answer (score 0):

Allowing this wouldn't make any sense. What would happen if you called the function without an implementation? A runtime error (that would be silly)? You could argue that it could a compile time error in some cases, but this is not possible if the exact type is not known (e.i. you pass a pointer to an instance of the derived class to a function).

Answer (score 0):

As many people have already stated, it sounds like either the base method shouldn't be pure virtual or you should rethink whether your derived class really ISA base.

However, it is possible to provide an implementation for the pure virtual method in the base class.  This can act like a default implementation for derived classes, but you still require the derived class to choose the base class's implementation explicity.

I don't know if that will help you with your problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. The convention in late bound languages when this situation occurs (as it legitimately might, but consider your design to see whether this method can be moved elsewhere, perhaps to its abstract class), is to raise an exception, and make sure that users of that method know that some implementations may raise that exception.

Answer (score 0):

Seems i faced with the same problem, when trying to hide method *getVertex()* in derived class.
Maybe it's help.

```
    class Body2D
{
public:
    virtual ~Body2D() = default;

    virtual double getCenter() const = 0;
    virtual double getVertex() const = 0;
};

class Ellipse : public Body2D
{
public:
    Ellipse(){};
    double getCenter() const override{};
private:
    double getVertex() const override{};
};
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30702206)

Answer (score -2):

Couldn't you just do

```
class Foo {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Bar {
public:
    virtual void foo() = delete;
};
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. There's not even any inheritance in the code shown here.